# How to Use SwipeRefreshLayout with Two Lists

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-listview

In one particular page of my Android app, based on user options, either a gridview or a listview is displayed. When the swipe is activated in the app, regardless of view displayed, I want to perform some arbitrary actions.

I've tried various configuration that usually lead to one list not being displayed properly or a list not scrolling or responding to touch events.

The xml layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/list_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <GridView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dip"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/gridview"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/listview"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

I display the pages using this logic

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
    boolean layout = settings.getBoolean("Layout", false);
    if (layout == true) {
        listview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gridview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}
```

And I configure the SwipeRefreshLayout like this:

```
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)list_view.findViewById(R.id.list_swipe_refresh_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if (!Updater.updateInProgress) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Update started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Updater.updateAll();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "An update is already in progress.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

With this specific configuration, if the app is configured to display a list nothing will appear, but if I switch the order of the GridView and ListView in the xml file the listview will appear properly but not the GridView.

How does one attach a SwipeRefreshLayout to more than one list/grid view?

Edit: To respond to one of the comments, when I try to put two SwipeRefreshLayouts in the FrameLayout, the first list/grid view defined will be unresponsive to swipes and taps. Here's the layout I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="90dip"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/listview"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

In the case above the gridview in completely unresponsive to touch events. If I swapped the listview for the gridview it would be the listview that was unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because SwipeRefreshLayout can hold only one scrollabel view. Add two SwipeRefreshLayout